# How to generate jsonDictionary or request body of following format in Swift 2.1?

Tags: json, post, swift2, nsdictionary, ios9

[image]

OR

[image]

I want to send above details into API POST body request. Please help me i'm very new to swift.

**UPDATE**

I've updated my code as per below solution. But curly braces and brackets are not getting properly how to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may code something like follows,

```
    var dict: [String : AnyObject] = ["userId" : "", "shops" : ""]
    var shops: Array<[String: AnyObject]> = []

    var shop : [String:AnyObject] = ["shopId" : "", "categeoryId" : "", "categoryNames": ""]

    let categoryID:Array<String> = ["1210", "1210", "1210"]
    let categoryNames:Array<String> = ["Repair", "RepairTest", "RepairTes3t"]

    shop.updateValue("13", forKey: "shopId")
    shop.updateValue(categoryID, forKey: "categeoryId")
    shop.updateValue(categoryNames, forKey: "categoryNames")

    shops.append(shop)
    dict.updateValue("7", forKey: "userId")
    dict.updateValue(shops, forKey: "shops")
    print(dict)
```

To send int POST API, just serialise it. You may serialise as follows.

```
 do {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
        print(jsonString)
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
```

Comment: Please don't call an object "json" until you serialize it to JSON data. It is confusing.

Comment: I can not pass jsonString in post request any other solutions ?